# Remote access Linksys WAG200G, not through WAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a network based on a SpeedTouch 706 modem/router, provided by my ISP. It is not possible to turn off NAT or DHCP on this device. Since it lacks wireless functionality, I added a Linksys WAG200G, by connecting LAN ports on both devices. Internet through WLAN works.

I would like to be able to manage the Linksys router/access point from an outside location, but I cannot get this to work.

The Linksys is configured for remote management on port 443 from any IP. The SpeedTouch is set to forward port 443 to the local IP of the Linksys. An nmap scan from the outside on my ISP-assigned IP on port 443 shows 'filtered'. If, as a test, I forward this port to my computer, nmap shows 'closed' (I have no service running on port 443), indicating that the portforwarding works.
I chose 443 since somebody suggested that the Linksys device requires an https connection — I have tried different ports as well, to no avail.

My suspicion is that the remote management functionality only works through the WAN side of the Linksys router. It has no such port, though. Only 4 LAN ports and a 'line' port for the telephone line (unused). I would like to keep both devices — even though technically the Linksys could probably take over all functions from the SpeedTouch — because of the silly reason that both devices are not located in the same rooms, and already properly fitted in their respective places.

I am interested in your suggestions to use the remote management functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about the remote management functionality - the Linksys expects it from the WAN, not the LAN. The LAN management typically is expected non-encrypted over port 80. You can forward the port, but bear in mind that anyone can see your router login credentials any time you connect to the router to modify settings. Ideally you'd connect to a proxy inside the network over HTTPS or SSH or VPN, and then connect to the Linksys.

Comment: Right. I see the risk of forwarding port 80. However, as a test, I did so, but still do not get access to or even a response from the router: nmap says filtered (instead of open/closed when forwarded to my laptop instead), as if no device is connected. What does this mean?

Comment: It means the port is either a) not forwarding correctly, or b) forwarded to the wrong device. Open and Closed mean that the port responded with "Hey, I'm open!" or "Hey! I'm closed! Go Away!", while filtered means that there was no response at all (either there's a firewall blocking it, or it's forwarded to a device that doesn't exist).